# Buffer GeoPandas dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas dataframe with a series of polygons in the `geometry` column. I also have a `bufferdist` column for each row containing an integer. The dataframe looks like

```
    bufferdist  geometry
0   600     POLYGON ((-122.9486846923828 48.65513944114847...
1   300     POLYGON ((-122.8642272949219 48.68053413474483...
```

How can I buffer each polygon in the dataframe to the `distance` of the `bufferdist` column?

I tried this

```
df['geometry'] = df.buffer(df.bufferdist)
```

but it returns the stacktrace

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-555bbdbc0044> in <module>()
----> 1 df['geometry'] = df.buffer(df.bufferdist)

C:\Users\nickp\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py in buffer(self, distance, resolution)
    298     def buffer(self, distance, resolution=16):
    299         return gpd.GeoSeries([geom.buffer(distance, resolution)
--> 300                              for geom in self.geometry],
    301                          index=self.index, crs=self.crs)
    302 

C:\Users\nickp\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    298     def buffer(self, distance, resolution=16):
    299         return gpd.GeoSeries([geom.buffer(distance, resolution)
--> 300                              for geom in self.geometry],
    301                          index=self.index, crs=self.crs)
    302 

C:\Users\nickp\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py in buffer(self, distance, resolution, quadsegs, cap_style, join_style, mitre_limit)
    582                 'Cannot compute offset from zero-length line segment')
    583         if cap_style == CAP_STYLE.round and join_style == JOIN_STYLE.round:
--> 584             return geom_factory(self.impl['buffer'](self, distance, res))
    585 
    586         if 'buffer_with_style' not in self.impl:

C:\Users\nickp\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py in __call__(self, this, *args)
     76     def __call__(self, this, *args):
     77         self._validate(this)
---> 78         return self.fn(this._geom, *args)

ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply apply a function to each row:

```
# for each row...
def buffer(row):
     return row.geometry.buffer(row.bufferid)

import geopandas as gpd
test = gpd.read_file("test_buffer.shp")
test.head(3)
      bufferid               geometry
0       300  POLYGON ((-0.6927016645326504 0.50320102432778...
1       100  POLYGON ((-0.5211267605633801 0.40332906530089...
2       600  POLYGON ((-0.7208706786171574 0.17285531370038...

# copy of the dataframe
buffered = test.copy()
# apply the function
buffered['geometry'] = buffered.apply(buffer, axis=1)
buffered.head(3)
     bufferid                geometry
0       300  POLYGON ((-226.0421711994954 198.5375833429314...
1       100  POLYGON ((-87.13968536542335 50.37557441425873...
2       600  POLYGON ((-317.4813433539906 509.7440504871266...
```

Or with [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

```
buffered = test.copy()
buffered['geometry'] = buffered.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.buffer(x.bufferid), axis=1)
buffered.head(3)
     bufferid                geometry
0       300  POLYGON ((-226.0421711994954 198.5375833429314...
1       100  POLYGON ((-87.13968536542335 50.37557441425873...
2       600  POLYGON ((-317.4813433539906 509.7440504871266...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gdf.buffer(size=gdf['size'])
```

You can pass a vector (np.array, pd.Series) as the size argument. However, the vector must be the same length as the GeoSeries which you want to find its buffer.