# How to create a multiple buffer using geopandas

Tags: geojson, geopandas

I want to create buffers from any point in a multiple point file.

I can do it with a constant buffer using **geopandas.buffer()**

```
track.geometry = track['geometry'].buffer(0.05)
track_line = track.iloc[2:].head()
```

but the buffer is applied to all points.

I would like to apply different buffer values. For example, using values in another column of the data frame or a new csv column value.

For example,

```
 ID,latitude,longitude,buffer_value
 0,45.4,-156.0,0.3
 1,45.53,-156.98,0.4
 2,45.66,-156.97,0.34
 3,45.79,-156.957,0.23
 4,45.93,-156.942,0.45
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258357/78446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next version of GeoPandas this will be possible with the `buffer` method (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/781), but for now you do it manually like this:

```
track['geometry'] = track.apply(
    lambda row: row.geometry.buffer(row.buffer_value), axis=1)
```

Comment: Very useful while the next version comes.