# Buffer a polyline by variable distance

Tags: buffer, polygon-creation

I have a list of points (x,y) that constitute a polyline, each point also has a value (v).

I want a polygon which is the buffer of the polyline with variable distance v. So at each point, the polygon is 2×v wide (if not overlapping), perpendicular to the direction of the polyline at that point.

A solution that is similar (but not exactly) is buffering each point with it's value, and then taking the union. I am looking for a solution that is computationally faster than this.

I am looking for a recipe/ method/ pseudocode, preferably in python but QGIS, ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro would also suffice.

All out of the box methods I have noted do not support variable distance, [shapely's buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer) or  [geopanda's buffer](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html)

Comment: Please decide which software you want to use. If you're looking for code, please provide useful coding attempts and example data. Please provide more details on your data, including a screenshot.

Comment: Computational performance and a variable-size buffer seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the structure of your dataframe but this may be a start.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258353/buffer-geopandas-dataframe-based-on-a-column-value

Comment: Not really, that use the geopandas.buffer that I have highlighted. That doesn't use variable buffer distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution with QGIS (I don't know if this will give you something better than your current workflow but it could be a starting point) :

1. Run the "Set M value" processing tool on your point, setting the M value as your value(v) field to get a PointM layer;
2. Run the "Points to path" processing tool on your PointM layer to get a LineM layer (you will need to have a field to order the point to create the line in the right order);
3. Run the "Variable width buffer (by M value)" processing tool on your lineM to get a variable width buffers based on the V (now M) value of the original point.

You may also create this process as a model or as a python script (each of the tool or model you create have an "export as Python" option to get you started)

[image]

It seems that the "Variable width buffer (by M value)" tool create a buffer of M/2 size on each side of the line so if you need a polygon that is 2×v wide set the M value as 2V in the first steep